# Messaging Exception in Sending SSL Mail

Tags: android, wifi, jakarta-mail

Excuse me, I have a question.
In programming development of mail sending for Android by JavaMail(1.4.7), MessagingException occured in connection of SMTPTransport and the program terminated abnormally. 
I succeeded with no trouble when using 3G and LTE, but failed after using Wi-Fi for more than ten seconds.

The source code is as below.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);

SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, null);
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, userEmail, null);

byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", userEmail, oauthToken).getBytes();
response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);
return transport;
```

The error is as below

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
       nested exception is:
         java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com/2404:6800:4008:c01::6c (port 587): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
         at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
         at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
         at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall on the wifi router blocking the port?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Mr.Ken.

I’m sorry for not replying sooner.
There was no port which blocks with wifi router.
As I said the other day, it's possible to send the mails for a few seconds after connecting.
Moreover, when I tried samsung(2.3.6) and samsung(4.1.2), they succeeded in connection.